# Tried installing the AirStatus repo from github but i keep getting an error

Tags: python, github, repo

After installing git and all the other requirements i tried `pip install git+https://github.com/faglo/AirStatus.git` to install the repo but i got a error saying:

```
ERROR: git+https://github.com/faglo/AirStatus.git does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

What can i do to fix this or are there any alternative methods to install this repo?

Answer (score 0):

If the repository doesn't provide the required configuration files, you can  clone the repository locally and then install the package using pip:

```
git clone https://github.com/faglo/AirStatus.git
cd AirStatus
pip install .
```

Comment: after doing this i got this error: 'ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.'

Comment: check if are you  in the correct directory (AirStatus) after running `git clone https://github.com/faglo/AirStatus.git`.

Comment: after writing `cd Airstatus` this is the directory : ` C:\Users\SHUBHRAT\AirStatus>`

Comment: see if whether the repository provides either a setup.py or pyproject.toml file.

Comment: it only provides a main.py file and an icons folder

Comment: and also If the repository doesn't have a proper Python packaging structure but contains code you want to use, you can simply clone the repository using `git clone` and use the code directly in your project.

Comment: and a 'venv' folder which contains further 2 more folders 'Scripts' and 'Lib' and inside them there are quite a few files

Comment: also ensure that you are using the correct version of Python according to the package. This information might also be available in the repository's documentation.

Comment: there are quite a few files with pywin32 in their names under the Lib folder so lemme try installing that

Comment: i already have it though

Comment: "This is Python 3.6 script" is mentioned at the beginning but I'm currently using Python 3.11 and 3.6 is not mentioned as a requirement there are other requirements though, which i have already fulfilled.

Comment: try this also , create a new venv and install python 3.6 and then try to pip install it. it could be a compatibility issue.